# Regex for validating input field

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I am working on an Angular application and have a form which requires user inputs and I am trying to create regex for validating these inputs.

I have the following:

```
//Regex enables letters, Umlaute, scharfes S, dot, dash and space 
//Spaces cannot be at the beginning or at the end and there is only one space between words enabled
readonly REGEX_FOR_VALID_NAMES = '^[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß]+(?:\\s[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß./]+)*$';
```

I wish to use it for name validation and it works great in the following examples:

Peter Smith
Peter-David Smith
T-Martin Smith
T M. Smith

But I am struggeling to add the possibility to accept dot at the beginning but not as the very first letter.

e.g.: **P.** David Smith

If I add it into the wirst bracet then it is accepted as the first character as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Does `^[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß][A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]+(?:\\s[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß./]+)*$` work?

Comment: @joH1 you'll also need to make the first character group optional or change the `+` to `*` on the second group if you want the same results as the original pattern. (Right now the changes will require 2 or more characters, not 1).

Comment: So `^[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß]?[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]+(?:\\s[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß./]+)*$` or `^[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß][A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]*(?:\\s[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß./]+)*$`.

Comment: I would recommend splitting the field to firstName-middleName-lastName - names are crazy, and will find a way to trip your validation.

Comment: @DM Right, good catch! OP probably wants your second regex because `[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß]?[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]+` is basically equivalent to `[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]+`

Comment: @Deltharis You shouldn't split names in several fields, it's the first curve of a spiral downward to madness. You don't know how right you are--[names are crazy](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: There is still a problem though--it allows several points. For example: `P.. David Smith` matches. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
readonly REGEX_FOR_VALID_NAMES = '^(?!.\\.{2})[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß][A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]*(?:\\s[A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß./]+)*$';
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ToTIMW/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.{2}                    '.' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß]         any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '-', 'ä', 'Ä', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ü', 'Ü', 'ß'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z-äÄöÖüÜß.]*       any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '-', 'ä', 'Ä', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ü', 'Ü', 'ß',
                           '.' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Za-z-                  any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to
    äÄöÖüÜß./]+              'z', '-', 'ä', 'Ä', 'ö', 'Ö', 'ü', 'Ü',
                             'ß', '.', '/' (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```